# Disable ngTable sorting

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have a fairly vanilla ng-table that I provided the followings parameters for:

```
$scope.newRoomsTableParams = new NgTableParams(
  {
    sorting: {}
  },
  {
    total: 0,
    getData: getNewRoomsData,
    counts: []
  }
);
```

I want to disable the sorting feature of ng-table entirely for all columns of the table. Specifically, I want the column headers to not be clickable and to not have the up/ down arrows.

Is this possible?

Edit #1: I guess the question really comes down to interpreting the [ng-table documentation](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/wiki/Configuring-your-table-with-ngTableParams) which I'm not able to figure out at this moment.

Edit #2: getNewRoomsData function is empty

```
function getNewRoomsData() {
  return $scope.newRoomsData;
}
```

Comment: to turn off the sort for a column, set the `sortable` property for the column to `false`.

Comment: you should be able to review the code from the documentation at http://ng-table.com/#/sorting/demo-enabling to figure out how to apply this to your dataset.

Comment: @Claies do you mean in an array or hash? Could you help me out with an example?

Comment: this would be done inside the `getNewRoomsData` function.  can you post the contents of that function for review?

Comment: @Claies sure. It's currently empty. $scope.newRoomsData is an array. Added function above in an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view (html code) remove the `filter` and `sortable` params of tag `<td>`.

Example, change this:

```
<table ng-table="vm.tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
  <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">

    <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
      {{user.name}}
    </td>

    <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
      {{user.age}}
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

To this:

```
<table ng-table="vm.tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
  <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">

    <!-- L@@k here below! -->

    <td title="'Name'">
      {{user.name}}
    </td>

    <td title="'Age'">
      {{user.age}}
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>**
```